# Word tables from HTML are not behaving correclty

Tags: html, ms-word, office365, aspose.words

I'm injecting HTML into a Word Mergefield (using Aspose) and it seems to work well and renders as I'd expect.

However, it seems to be treated as one table rather than two. Any text or paragraphs inserted between the tables is visible during editing but not when printing. When you print, the tables bunch together as one and anything in between is removed.

Is there anything I can change in the HTML to allow the tables to be independent when rendered in Word and have at least one line break between them? The @variables are replaced with text from the database. Using Office 365 (not the cloud one, the one installed locally)

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100% ; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%;">@Statement</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100% ; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" >
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height: 12px; width: 100%">
            <td style="width: 50%; height: 12px; text-align: left ; padding: 0px;">@Bank</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 12px; text-align: right ; padding: 0px;">Sort Code:</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px; text-align: right ; padding: 0px;">@SortCode</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 12px">
            <td style="width: 50%; height: 12px; text-align: left ; padding: 0px;">@Line1</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 12px; text-align: right ; padding: 0px;">Account No:</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px ; text-align: right ; padding: 0px;">@AccountNo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 12px">
            <td style="width: 50%; height: 12px; text-align: left ; padding: 0px;">@Line2</td>
            <td style="width: 15% ; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20% ; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 15% ; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 12px">
            <td style="width: 50%; height: 12px; text-align: left ; padding: 0px;">@Line3</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 12px">
            <td style="width: 50%; height: 12px; text-align: left ; padding: 0px;">@PostCode</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is the behavior of MS Word that Microsoft Word merges two or more consecutive Tables into one big Table if there are no Paragraphs in between them. In your HTML, you can simply add an empty paragraph between Tables:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100% ; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%;">@Statement1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:1pt">
    <span>&#xa0;</span>
</p>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100% ; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height: 12px; width: 100%">
            <td style="width: 50%; height: 12px; text-align: left ; padding: 0px;">@Bank</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 12px; text-align: right ; padding: 0px;">Sort Code:</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px; text-align: right ; padding: 0px;">@SortCode</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 12px">
            <td style="width: 50%; height: 12px; text-align: left ; padding: 0px;">@Line1</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 12px; text-align: right ; padding: 0px;">Account No:</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px ; text-align: right ; padding: 0px;">@AccountNo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 12px">
            <td style="width: 50%; height: 12px; text-align: left ; padding: 0px;">@Line2</td>
            <td style="width: 15% ; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20% ; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 15% ; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 12px">
            <td style="width: 50%; height: 12px; text-align: left ; padding: 0px;">@Line3</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 12px">
            <td style="width: 50%; height: 12px; text-align: left ; padding: 0px;">@PostCode</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 15%; height: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: That worked perfectly -- thanks. The only changes I had to make were adding a `<br>` to create a line break along with an increase in font size in the empty paragraph.